# Leafletjs Popup Layer not correct position on page load

Tags: javascript, leaflet, popup

please help me. My popups Leaflet JS don't seem right than the marker position on page load.
Here is my code

```
var arrIcon = new LeafIcon({iconUrl: './dist/images/ruasjalan/icon_jalan.png'});

var data = [{"id":6,"nama":"Kyai Maja","lat":"-8.066713041117994","lng":"111.89851999282838"},{"id":5,"nama":"Jl. Panglima Sudirman","lat":"-8.058592256820186","lng":"111.90756797703217"}];

var markers = {};

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var ruas = data[i];
    var popupLocation = new L.LatLng(ruas.lat, ruas.lng);
    var popupContent = '<div align="center"><b>' + ruas.nama + '</b></div>', popruas = new L.Popup({autoClose:false,autoPan:false,keepInView:true,closeButton:false,closeOnEscapeKey:false,maxWidth : 560});
    popruas.setLatLng(popupLocation);
    popruas.setContent(popupContent);
    mapall.addLayer(popruas);
    markers[ruas.id] = L.marker([ruas.lat, ruas.lng], {icon: arrIcon}).bindPopup('<div align="center"><b>' + ruas.nama + '</b></div>').addTo(mapall);
    markers[ruas.id]._icon.id = ruas.id;
    markers[ruas.id].off('click');
    markers[ruas.id].on('click', function() {return;});
}
```

Here is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Please share your `arrIcon` code. You need to set the proper `iconAnchor` and `popupAnchor` values

Comment: I already edited it..

Comment: @@Yustinus Wndy. Please check my answer and let me now if it answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the following code in order to make your icon display properly.
Regardless of the size you need to define `iconAnchor` and `popupAnchor` values. For instance lets assume your icon has 128x128px dimensions. This is too big. So you define smaller dimensions using iconSize and then define the suitable iconAnchor to place the tooltip properly.

```
var arrIcon = new L.Icon({
    // place here your icon url - I placed a similar just to illustrate how it should be
    iconUrl: 'https://icon-icons.com/icons2/936/PNG/128/road-perspective_icon-icons.com_73428.png',
    iconSize: [25, 41],
    iconAnchor: [10, 0],
    popupAnchor: [2, -40]
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <title>Quick Start - Leaflet</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin="" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og==" crossorigin=""></script>



</head>

<body>



  <div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
  <script>
    var mapall = L.map('mapid').setView([-8.066713041117994, 111.89851999282838], 14);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
      maxZoom: 18,
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
        '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
        'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
      id: 'mapbox.streets'
    }).addTo(mapall);

    var arrIcon = new L.Icon({
      iconUrl: 'https://icon-icons.com/icons2/936/PNG/128/road-perspective_icon-icons.com_73428.png',
      iconSize: [25, 41],
      iconAnchor: [10, 0],
      popupAnchor: [2, -40]
    });
    var data = [{
      "id": 6,
      "nama": "Kyai Maja",
      "lat": "-8.066713041117994",
      "lng": "111.89851999282838"
    }, {
      "id": 5,
      "nama": "Jl. Panglima Sudirman",
      "lat": "-8.058592256820186",
      "lng": "111.90756797703217"
    }];

    var markers = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var ruas = data[i];
      var popupLocation = new L.LatLng(ruas.lat, ruas.lng);
      var popupContent = '<div align="center"><b>' + ruas.nama + '</b></div>',
        popruas = new L.Popup({
          autoClose: false,
          autoPan: false,
          keepInView: true,
          closeButton: false,
          closeOnEscapeKey: false,
          maxWidth: 560
        });
      popruas.setLatLng(popupLocation);
      popruas.setContent(popupContent);
      mapall.addLayer(popruas);
      markers[ruas.id] = L.marker([ruas.lat, ruas.lng], {
        icon: arrIcon
      }).bindPopup('<div align="center"><b>' + ruas.nama + '</b></div>').addTo(mapall);
      markers[ruas.id]._icon.id = ruas.id;
      markers[ruas.id].off('click');
      markers[ruas.id].on('click', function() {
        return;
      });
    }
  </script>



</body>

</html>
```